# why local mirroring is not working with running docker container despite adding volumes?

Tags: docker, express, docker-compose

whenever I make any changes to my code it doesn't reflect on the running container despite adding volumes to both images,
I tried docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yaml up --build
here is my express and docker file

**express**

```
import path  from 'path'
import express from 'express'
import {  fileURLToPath } from 'url';


const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url))
const app = express()
const PORT = 3000;

app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.get('/api', (req,res) => {
  res.render('pages/home')
})

app.listen(PORT)
```

whenever i make changes to the home file i need to rebuild the image, defintley that's a nightmare if i have to rebuild the image everytime I change anything how am i going to develop then, so i added volumes but still I don't see any changes

**docker compose**

```
version: '3'
services:
  dev-nginx:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./nginx
    container_name: dev-nginx
    links:
      - dev-node
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./client/public:/usr/share/nginx/html
    depends_on:
      - dev-node
  dev-webpack:
    build:
      context: ./client
    container_name: dev-webpack
    volumes:
      - ./client:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    stdin_open: true
  dev-node:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./server
    container_name: dev-node
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
      - PORT=3000
    volumes:
      - ./server:/app
      - /app/node_modules
```

Comment: Needing to rebuild the image when you change the source is normal (and consistent with how compiled languages like Go or Rust work).  Can you use a local non-Docker Node for day-to-day development?

Comment: Well that is weird because despite I don’t have any experience with docker i remember running a container that listens to change but sadly i lost the source code,? Is it hard to achieve this ?

Comment: Your question is really hard to grasp. Could you elaborate a little bit more? What are you changing?  What is the home file? What does your setup look like?

Comment: @AlphaBeta well I have 2 folders client and server, client is a webpack based config will handle my css, images, and js file, and the server folder have express with pug template engine to handle api request, so i want the docker container to be updated when i make changes to my pug template or css or js etc... I added the volumes but it doesn't seem to be working,I hope i elaborated enough

Comment: You should update your question with something depicting your directory structure and a detailed explanation of what you would expect if you changed which file. If you are unfamiliar with hot reloading, I guess this is what you are looking for.